# Rails Missing JBuilder File Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, ruby-on-rails-5, jbuilder

I've been trying to use Fullcalendar to display events from a JSON feed. The events in the JSON feed are generated by SchoolEventsController. However, the events won't show up on Fullcalendar. Also, viewing the JSON file(school_events/index.json.jbuilder) produces this error:

*ActionController::UnknownFormat at /calendar.json
SchoolEventsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.
request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []*

I think I have narrowed my problem down to these two files:

index function in **school_events_controller.rb**:

```
class SchoolEventsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @events = @calendar.events
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json # index.json.jbuilder?
        end
    end

end
```

**school_events/index.json.jbuilder**:

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
    date_format = event.all_day? ? '%Y-%m-%d' : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    json.id event.id
    json.title event.name
    json.start event.start_time.strftime(date_format)
    json.end event.end_time.strftime(date_format)
    json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?('/')
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'mime-types', '~> 3.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'
gem 'closure_tree', '~> 6.0'
gem 'ancestry',     '~> 3.0'
gem 'ranked-model', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'mailgun_rails', '0.9.0'
gem 'nested_form', '0.3.2'
gem 'event-calendar', github: 'kirandc/event_calendar', require: 'event_calendar'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.7'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.1'
gem 'flash_cookie_session', github: 'trevorturk/flash_cookie_session'
gem 'date_validator', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',        '~> 4.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails',     '~> 6.0'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails', '~> 1.3.2'
gem 'fancybox2-rails', github: 'ChallahuAkbar/fancybox2-rails', tag: 'v0.3.0'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.3'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'
gem 'pghero', '~> 1.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 7.0'
gem 'bourbon',            '~> 4.2'
gem 'normalize-rails',    '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails',         '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier',           '~> 3.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', require: false
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.13.0'
gem 'recaptcha', '~> 4.1', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'yajl-ruby', '~> 1.3', require: false
gem 'tinymce-rails', '~> 4.3'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.2'
gem 'image_optim',      '~> 0.25.0'
gem 'image_optim_pack', '~> 0.5.0'

group :production do
  gem 'redis-rails', '~> 5'
  gem 'sitemap_generator', '~> 5.1'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'rollbar', '~> 2.11'
end

group :development, :production do
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 0.10.1'
  gem 'whenever', '~> 0.9.4', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',               '~> 3.7',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler',       '~> 1.1',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-faster-assets', '~> 1.0',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',         '~> 1.1',   require: false
  gem 'better_errors',     '~> 2.1'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7.2'
  gem 'thin', '~> 1.6'
  gem 'guard',            '~> 2.13'
  gem 'guard-livereload', '~> 2.5', require: false
  gem 'brakeman', '~> 3.3', require: false
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.3'
  gem 'letter_opener', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'yard', '~> 0.9.5'
  gem 'bullet', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'rubocop',       '~> 0.4',    require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', '~> 1.7',    require: false
  gem 'scss_lint',     '~> 0.54.0', require: false
  gem 'progress_bar', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec',   '~> 1.0'
  gem 'spring-commands-rubocop', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.6'
  gem 'rspec',       '~> 3.4'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', require: false
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.14.0', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5', require: false
  gem 'webmock', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'accept_values_for', '~> 0.7.2'
end
```

relevant routes in **routes.rb**:

```
scope defaults: { calendar_name: 'School Calendar' } do
    get '/calendar/list',             to: 'school_events#list',    as: :school_calendar_list
    get '/calendar/editors',          to: 'school_events#editors', as: :editors_school_calendar
    get '/calendar(/:year(/:month))', to: 'school_events#index',
                                      as: :school_calendar,
                                      constraints: { year: /20(?:1[1-9]|20)/, month: /\d{1,2}/ }
    resources :school_events, path: '/events', except: [:index]
  end

  scope '/calendar' do
    get '/edit', to: 'school_events#edit_calendar',
                 defaults: { calendar_name: 'School Calendar' },
                 as: :edit_school_calendar
    put '/',     to: 'school_events#update_calendar',
                 defaults: { calendar_name: 'School Calendar' }

    resources :google_syncs, only: %i[new create destroy], as: :school_calendar_google_syncs do
      get :authorize, on: :collection
    end
  end
```

When I replace `format.json` in SchoolEventsController with `format.json { render json: @events }`, calendar.json will output(in JSON) all the desired events from my database. I don't want to use those outputs because I would need a messy workaround to rename all the attributes to comply with Fullcalendar's requirements. Does anyone have a way to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm using Rails 5

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: @MatthewBorg Hello! I have added my Gemfile. About gem 'jbuilder', while I have `gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'` in Gemfile, `bundle show jbuilder` says that my version is 1.5.3.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're having given what you've shown. But I don't think you need the `respond_to` block for `jbuilder` to work. your controller could just be `def index; @events = @calendar.events; end`

Comment: @MatthewBorg I've removed the respond_to block. The error is still there. Would there be a problem if I have an school_events/index.html.erb

Comment: no that shouldn't cause any problems. `jbuilder` sets up a template handler for files ending in `.jbuilder`. It should work alongside your `html.erb` templates. To elaborate, I started a new Rails 5.0 app with ruby 2.3.1 and your Gemfile and a `pg` database with a simple `posts` scaffold (with `posts/index.html.erb` and `posts/index.json.jbuilder`) and i'm having no issues rendering the `jbuilder` template, whether my `index` action looks like yours or I leave out the `respond_to` block

Comment: just one more idea, could you post the lines from `routes.rb` that define this route?

Comment: @MatthewBorg I added some of my routes. These should be the ones dealing with my page.

Comment: I'm sorry! Nothing seems wrong with the routes as far as I can tell, and the `jbuilder` file looks fine too. Wish I could help but I can't reproduce this error. It might sound silly, but was `jbuilder` installed recently? Are you booting the server with `bundle exec`? Maybe if not then `$ bundle install && bundle exec rails s` will work

Comment: it's up to `jbuilder` to load a template handler for `.jbuilder` files, and without it Rails doesn't know how to handle them. Maybe the cause is `jbuilder` is not being initialized. also try `bundle exec spring stop && bundle exec rails s`

Comment: @MatthewBorg Oh... wow... thank you so so much! Those last few commands did just the trick! (plus I deleted `json.url event_url(event, format: :html)` from my index.json.jbuilder). A hundred upvotes for you if I could!

Comment: no problem! the `jbuilder` initializer just wasn't getting hit. I think you will be fine with the `json.url event_url(event, format: :html)` line if you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ bundle exec spring stop
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec rails s
```

`jbuilder` has an initialization hook that defines the `.jbuilder` template handler. Without it, Rails doesn't know what to do with `.jbuilder` template files. The initializer isn't getting run, maybe because `spring` never restarted when `jbuilder` was installed, or `jbuilder` wasn't installed.

Answer (score 3):

#### Rails 7?

If you're upgrading to Rails 7, a likely source of this error is that you need to specify the formatting type of your template:

```
# in my view
render(template: "line_items/line_items", formats: :json)  # must specify json format
```

It's a small detail, but can leave one perplexed for many hours.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically related to what was asked, but I got here due to that same error on my Rails API-only app, when running the request specs.

Error:

```
Failure/Error: get url
     
     ActionController::UnknownFormat:
       Api::V1::TodosController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.
     
       request.formats: ["text/html"]
       request.variant: []
```

So, when running the request specs, you have to specify the headers, like so:

```rb
get url, headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json" }
```

You can even extract that to *./spec/support/request_helpers.rb* to use it just as `headers` instead:

```rb
# spec/support/request_helpers.rb
module RequestHelpers
  def headers
     { "Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json" }
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RequestHelpers, type: :request
end
```

Just hoping to help more newbies out there like myself!